# SlickGrid V2.0 Column name/id does not follow column when dragging

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have an application (using SlickGrid) where I need to get the column name or id at any time when user clicks on a cell (this pulls up a menu specific to the data in that column/cell).  Grid works fine initially but if the column is moved (drag/drop), the column name/id does not follow the drop but remains mapped to it's initial column position.

Has anyone else seen this and, if so, how did you fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reuse the list of columns defined in your html code? You should get the list of columns from the grid instead. The following code should do what you are expecting (i.e. printout the name of the column in which you clicked a cell):

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e,args) {                
  var allColumns=grid.getColumns();
  console.log(allColumns[args.cell].name);
});
```

You can add that code in one of the examples provided with the source code (say "example3-editing.html"), drag-drop some columns around and check the console after clicking on a cell.